# Homepage Slider isn't displaying well on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.main-slider-img > img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-slider-content {
        left: 15%;
        margin-top: -146px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
    }
    .main-slider-content > h2{
        line-height: 50px;
        padding: 0 25px;
        background-color: #68a868;
        display: inline-block;
        text-shadow:2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    .main-slider-content > h3{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: 45px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    .main-slider-content > h3::after {
        
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -8px;
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        height: 3px;
        left: 0;
        width: 80px;
    }
    .main-slider-content a{
        line-height: 38px;
        padding: 4px 22px 0;
        color: #fff;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .main-slider-content a > i{
        margin-left: 6px; 
    }
    .main-slider-content a:hover{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #5cb85c;
    }
    .main-slider.owl-theme .owl-controls {
        margin-top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-slider.owl-theme .owl-prev {
        left: 20px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .main-slider.owl-theme .owl-next {
        right: 20px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .main-slider.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 88px;
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        padding: 0 10px;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease ;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease ;
        -ms-transition: all .5s ease ;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease ;
        transition: all .5s ease ;
    }
    .main-slider.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div:hover{
        background-color: rgba(92, 184, 92, 0.4);
    }
    .slide-2 {
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        margin-top: -90px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slide-2 > h3 {
        font-size: 45px;
        line-height: 55px;
    }
    .main-slider-content.slide-2 > h3:after{
        display: none;
    }
    .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0);
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

.main-slider-img.position-r > img{
  height: auto;
 }
 .main-slider-content{
  left: 5%;
  top: 8%;
  margin-top: 0;
 }
 .main-slider-content > h3{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
 }
 .main-slider-content > h4{
  line-height: 22px;
 }
 .slide-2{
  margin-top: 0;
 } 
 .slide-2 > h3{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
            <div class="main-slider">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="main-slider-img position-r">
                        <img src="http://www.trezalliance.com/img/s1.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="main-slider-img position-r">
                        <img src="http://www.trezalliance.com/img/s2.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have issues with my homepage slider whenever I shrink my browser or open my website on a mobile phone the slider image looses proper form and on same slider, the slides do not change automatically. I have spent a lot trying to figure that out.

[My URL](http://trezalliance.com/)

Comment: Please provide your code directly in your question. People are more likely to help you if they can see your code directly than if they have to visit your website and view the source code there.

Comment: This I've done now, I'm sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your responsive.css on line 10 and line 346

```
.main-slider-img.position-r > img {
    height: 500px;
}
```

to

```
.main-slider-img.position-r > img {
    height: auto;
}
```

And add

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .main-slider.owl-theme .owl-controls {
        top: 20%
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replies, I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

in your css you have.

```
.main-slider-img.position-r > img {
    height: 500px;
}
```

change to

```
.main-slider-img.position-r > img {
    height: auto;
}
```

in all your media queries

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replies, I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work